# Javascript add a regex inside a function for validation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a regular expression inside a JavaScript function. I've never done something like this before. How is this done? I've got the length part correct, but the regex has me stuck.

```
if(searchTerm('Ford GT')) {
    alert ('Query OK');
} else {

    alert ('Invalid query');
}


function searchTerm(query) {
    if( (query.length >= 2 && query.length <= 24) && (query.test('/^[a-z0-9()\- ]+$/i')) )  {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) the syntax is `regex.test(string)`

```
/^[a-z0-9()\- ]+$/i.test(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchTerm(query) {
    var regex = /^[a-z0-9()\- ]{2,24}$/i;
    return regex.test(query);
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc. It's normally a good idea to add some commentary around the code in answers, if only so they don't get flagged up for review.

Answer (score 0):

**test** is method of the RegExp Object (try `console.log({}.toString.call(/\d/));`), not of the String Object. Thats's why use the syntax `regex.test(string)`.
Also your function can be rewritten more compact:

```
function searchTerm(query) {
    return query.length >= 2 && query.length <= 24 && /^[-a-z\d() ]+$/i.test(query);
}
```